# Probability, question with bins and balls

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, balls-in-bins

This is the translated version of the question:

> Allocating randomly 40 balls in 50 bins, what is the probability that a certain cell contains exactly 30 balls? What is the probability that a certain bin contains k balls, for k being 0,1,2,3,...,40?

I really don't know how to start this problem. Maybe a single hint is all I need to do this problem. 
It is given in my exercise book, and I don't have any solution for this.

Comment: could it be balls and bins ? I'll add the tag just in case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question implies that we are choosing one cell (or bin) and examining whether that cell gets $30$ balls or not.

In that case we have a fixed probability per ball of $\frac{1}{50}$ for getting the ball and $\frac{49}{50}$ for not getting it in that cell. We also have $\binom {40}{30}$ different sequences for getting that set of outcomes, giving the probability

$$\binom {40}{30}\frac{1^{30}49^{10}}{50^{40}}$$

for a given cell of getting $30$ balls exactly.

The case for $k$ balls in a given cell follows straightforwardly.

Comment: Is this a binomial model that you have followed to derive to that conclusion? Anyway thanks for the solution, clear and concise.

Comment: Yes, the various possible numbers of balls in a particular cell are captured in an expansion of $\left( \frac{1}{50} + \frac{49}{50} \right)^{40}$